# Response Isn't Converting To JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs

I'm trying to take info from a React form and post it to my Rails database, but I get an error `"unexpected token '<' at position 0"` which means my response is still HTML and not JSON.

Here's my code:

```
export const createCar = car => {
return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/cars/create`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ car: car })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(car => {
        dispatch(addCar(car))
        dispatch(resetCarForm())
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error + 'createCar POST failed'))
}
```

}

Is there a reason why it's not converting to JSON?

*Additionally, I don't seem to be able to drop debugger into my code, or at least in this function - do I need to import it or something?*

Comment: is this catching in error or failing in rendering ?

Comment: It's catching in error

Comment: what are your expected response format from your post api response. Can you please add more details.

Comment: would be better, if you post yr rails action also...

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that your server is sending you back HTML and then you are trying to parse it in `response.json()`

use a try/catch in this block:

```
export const createCar = car => {
return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/cars/create`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ car: car })
    })
    .then(response => {
         try {
            return response.json()
         } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
         }
    })
    .then(car => {
        dispatch(addCar(car))
        dispatch(resetCarForm())
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error + 'createCar POST failed'))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however it still ends up logging (error + 'createCar POST failed'), I'm not sure why it skipped over the Try/Catch

Comment: Can you try to put the POST in postman? I am sure that your server is the issue here.

Comment: Looks like I'm not posting to the correct route: ` "exception": "#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] \"/api/cars/create\">"` but when I ran rake routes I have an api/cars#create route. Any ideas?

Comment: Try posting to `/api/cars`.

Comment: @hashrocket Posting to `api/cars` gets a 400 Bad Request, `param is missing or is empty: cars`. It may either be namespacing or I'm calling the wrong param in my controller